# Missing (?) \begingroup in the definition of \enddocument

Tags: latex-base

**Disclaimer** While re-reading the question before posting it, it occurred to me that I'm referring to the LaTeX kernel of my computer (TeXLive 2017, `\fmtversion`=`2017-04-15`). The question is in some sense only a historical curiosity.

---

Environments, as we know, build a group. For what I'm asking here the point is that

```
\begin{foo}
```

becomes (after the usual checks)

```
\begingroup\foo
```

and analogously

```
\end{foo}
```

does basically

```
\endfoo\endgroup
```

Now, my problem is that the `{document}` environment is defined by declaring directly `\document` and `\enddocument`. The definition of the former is

```
\def\document{\endgroup
              % [THE WHOLE REST ]
}
```

and `source2e` comments the first `\endgroup` by saying

> Cancel the `\begingroup` from `\begin`.

Therefore, since `\end{document}` will expand to `\enddocument\endgroup`, for symmetry reasons I expected the definition of `\enddocument` to involve an unmatched `\begingroup`; however, I have find none:

```
\def\enddocument{%
   \let\AtEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@enddocumenthook
   \@checkend{document}%
   \clearpage
   \begingroup
     \if@filesw
       \immediate\closeout\@mainaux
       \let\@setckpt\@gobbletwo
       \let\@newl@bel\@testdef
       \@tempswafalse
       \makeatletter \@@input\jobname.aux
     \fi
     \@dofilelist
     \ifdim \font@submax >\fontsubfuzz\relax
       \@font@warning{Size substitutions with differences\MessageBreak
                  up to \font@submax\space have occurred.\@gobbletwo}%
     \fi
     \@defaultsubs
     \@refundefined
     \if@filesw
       \ifx \@multiplelabels \relax
         \if@tempswa
           \@latex@warning@no@line{Label(s) may have changed.
               Rerun to get cross-references right}%
         \fi
       \else
         \@multiplelabels
       \fi
     \fi
   \endgroup
   \deadcycles\z@\@@end}
```

Obviously the groups *are* somehow balanced: if I use `\document` instead of `\begin{document}` I get an expected error about an extra `\endgroup`, but writing `\enddocument` directly instead of `\end{document}` works.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\enddocument` doesn't need to balance groups because `\end` is (was in 2017):

```latex
\def\end#1{%
  \csname end#1\endcsname\@checkend{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi}
```

so `\enddocument` (and the final `\@@end` to stop TeX) is executed before the `\endgroup` is seen, so that's not a worry.  `\enddocument` does have to do `\@checkend{document}` by itself though, because that will also not happen from the definition of `\end`.

As a matter of fact, generic environment hooks like `etoolbox`'s `\AfterEndEnvironment{document}{<code>}` or, with `lthooks`, `\AddToHook{env/document/after}{<code>}` are never executed because they appear after the code for `\enddocument`.

Comment: Oh boy, I'm so stupid... it was right there under my nose `:-(`

Comment: @campa I disagree. Getting the timing right with environments is often tricky :)

Comment: Yeah, but it's not like I had never used some `\expandafter\@@end` trick myself before... I *had* a feeling this morning that I should've stayed in bed `:-)`.

Comment: @campa That's _never_ a bad decision ;-)